# Hardware fingerprint class in C#

Tags: c#, hardware, fingerprint

I'm using the following class to generate a unique hardware ID for a basic software licencing system.
The problem is that in some cases the fingerprint produced is different, without any hardware change.

I have not developed a client-side debugging system to isolate the component that causes the problem, so i'd like to ask if and under what conditions the following code could generate different IDs for the same hardware.

I already removed the network adaptor part (caused variations when many adaptors existed) and the hard disk part (problems when a usb drive was attached).
But the remaining components' IDs should remain the same, even after software changes and windows updates, isn't so?

```
public static class FingerPrint
{
private static string fingerPrint = string.Empty;

//--------------------------------------

public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
{
    var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}

//--------------------------------------

public static string Value()
{
        string cpu = cpuId();
        string bios = biosId();
        string bas = baseId();
        string video = videoId();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fingerPrint))
        {
            fingerPrint = GetHash("CPU >> " + cpu + "\nBIOS >> " +
                bios + "\nBASE >> " + bas
                + "\nVIDEO >> " + video
                + "\n some_salt");
        }
        return Base64Encode(fingerPrint);
}

//--------------------------------------

private static string GetHash(string s)
{
    MD5 sec = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();

    byte[] bt = enc.GetBytes(s);
    return GetHexString(sec.ComputeHash(bt));
}

//--------------------------------------

private static string GetHexString(byte[] bt)
{
    string s = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < bt.Length; i++)
    {
        byte b = bt[i];
        int n, n1, n2;
        n = (int)b;
        n1 = n & 15;
        n2 = (n >> 4) & 15;
        if (n2 > 9)
            s += ((char)(n2 - 10 + (int)'A')).ToString();
        else
            s += n2.ToString();
        if (n1 > 9)
            s += ((char)(n1 - 10 + (int)'A')).ToString();
        else
            s += n1.ToString();
        if ((i + 1) != bt.Length && (i + 1) % 2 == 0) s += "-";
    }
    return s;
}

//--------------------------------------

//Return a hardware identifier
private static string identifier(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty, string wmiMustBeTrue)
{
    string result = "";
    System.Management.ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass(wmiClass);

    System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
    foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        if (mo[wmiMustBeTrue].ToString() == "True")
        {
            //Only get the first one
            if (result == "")
            {
                    result = mo[wmiProperty].ToString();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

//--------------------------------------

//Return a hardware identifier
private static string identifier(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty)
{
    string result = "";
    System.Management.ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass(wmiClass);

    System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
    foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        //Only get the first one
        if (result == "")
        {
                result = mo[wmiProperty].ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

//--------------------------------------

private static string cpuId()
{
    //Uses first CPU identifier available in order of preference
    //Don't get all identifiers, as it is very time consuming

    string retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "UniqueId");

    if (retVal == "") //If no UniqueID, use ProcessorID
    {
        retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "ProcessorId");
        if (retVal == "") //If no ProcessorId, use Name
        {
            retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "Name");
            if (retVal == "") //If no Name, use Manufacturer
            {
                retVal = identifier("Win32_Processor", "Manufacturer");
            }
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}

//--------------------------------------

//BIOS Identifier
private static string biosId()
{
    return identifier("Win32_BIOS", "Manufacturer")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "SMBIOSBIOSVersion")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "IdentificationCode")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "SerialNumber")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "ReleaseDate")
        + identifier("Win32_BIOS", "Version");
}

//--------------------------------------

//Motherboard ID
private static string baseId()
{
    return identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Model")
        + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Manufacturer")
        + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "Name")
        + identifier("Win32_BaseBoard", "SerialNumber");
}

//--------------------------------------

//Primary video controller ID
private static string videoId()
{
    return identifier("Win32_VideoController", "Name");
}
}
```

Comment: You appear to be asking whether software updates change the BIOS version number, which is a "How does my computer work?" question, not a programming question.  Anyway, the BIOS is software (firmware), and BIOS (firmware) update will definitely change the reported BIOS version even when the hardware is the same.

Comment: Other things, like the "Model" of the CPU or the "Name" of the video card, might depend on the driver version... old drivers won't recognize newer hardware and would return a generic string, while new drivers would return an accurate string.  And a generic/safe mode driver might return a string found in the PCI plug-and-play descriptor rather than the vendor's naming scheme.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the answer, but my users reported fingerprint changes with no BIOS update at all.

Comment: So driver updates could be a reason for the problem. Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

You may have several network cards or video cards on your computer, which you should pay attention to during identification.
When you use Remote Desktop, Windows adds a graphics card to your hardware!!!!
[several network cards - several HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wpNV.png)

[Remote Desktop Adaptor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHJXf.png)

```
        private static string identifier(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty)
    {
        String result = "";
        System.Management.ManagementClass mc =  new System.Management.ManagementClass(wmiClass);
        System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
        foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            //Only get the first one
            if (result == "")
            {
                try
                {
                    if (wmiClass.EQ("Win32_DiskDrive") )
                    {
                        if (mo.Path.ToString().Contains("PHYSICALDRIVE0"))
                        {
                            result = mo[wmiProperty] != null ? mo[wmiProperty].ToString() : "";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (wmiClass.EQ("Win32_VideoController"))
                    {
                        if (mo.Path.ToString().Contains("VideoController1"))
                        {
                            result = mo[wmiProperty] != null ? mo[wmiProperty].ToString() : "";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (wmiClass.EQ("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
                    {
                            result = mo[wmiProperty] != null ? mo[wmiProperty].ToString() : "";
                        if(result!="")
                            break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = mo[wmiProperty] != null ? mo[wmiProperty].ToString() : "";
                        break;
                    }
                    
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```